# Workflow to use a sub-module typescript written module into a non-typescript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I'm having a private typescript module that is a dependency of another major project. This dependency is achieved by having the typescript repository as sub-module and installed using npm to the local sub-folder. The typescript module can compile into JavaScript on its dist folder and by doing so the major module that consumes it can make use of it without issues. But here is my problem, the dist folder isn't committed to the typescript repository.

What should be the workflow to follow in order to consume this typescript module from a JavaScript-only major project? The best I can think at this moment is to instruct someone, or something, to run the `$ tsc` command before using the major project but it's "annoying" since it isn't a transparent step. If this is a weird approach, what would be a more ideal approach? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You said you're installing the module using npm. Git repository should only contain Typescript code, but the code you're publishing to the npm registry should be Javascript, so the compiled version of your module. Isn't it what you're doing right now?

Comment: It is installed referencing the local folder. This is `$ npm install ../../whatever`. None is of the projects are actually published, they're all private modules. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. Assuming you're not planning to have a private npm registry using e.g. [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) you can simply commit the `dist` folder. This is definitely the simplest option and it's not completely unheard of, I'd probably go with that option.
2. This solution is actually quite unusual, but it's pretty clever and it works. You could add a `postinstall` script in package.json of your TypeScript package that would run `tsc` after installing the package. The downside is that you'd have to add `typescript` as your dependency, which is not ideal (it should generally be a dev dependency, in which case it wouldn't be installed in the project using the package), but for some it might not be a big deal at all.
3. Instead of installing the package, you could use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) and then have a script in your main project that would compile it. You'd have to run it every time something changes in that package, though. You could also append it to your `npm start` script, so it runs before it, e.g. `"start": "npm compile-package && webpack"` (assuming your current `start` script is `"start": "webpack"`). It doesn't scale very well though.
4. If your Javascript project uses Babel (and I'd assume so considering you said it's a "major" project) you could change its config so it transpiles Typescript for you using `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`, however it can be a bit complicated, IIRC e.g. projects created with create-react-app by default don't recompile the code from `node_modules`.

There are probably more solutions, but I'd probably go with 1 or 2.

Comment: This an absolute fantastic answer and it'll help me to decide for the right solution. Thank you!